# Understanding でございます in「ただ今ご紹介いただいた田中でございます」

Tags: keigo, sonkeigo

I was looking up ございます in デジタル大辞泉. I found an odd sentence example

> （２）（補助動詞）補助動詞「ある」の意の丁寧語。「すでにお願いして―・す」「いかがお過ごしで―・しょうか」「**ただ今ご紹介いただいた田中で―・す**」「おめでとう―・す」「いっそ死にとう―・す」

I'm puzzled why でございます is used in「ただ今ご紹介いただいた田中でございます」. Since the speaker is referring to 田中, not himself, he should use 尊敬語. Thus, he should use でいらっしゃいます, not でございます. でございます is used for inanimate objects, right?

Also, I wonder who is doing 紹介 in this sentence? 田中?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tanaka is the speaker here. でございます is also a humble form of です. Someone who merits the use (by Tanaka) of the honorific ご紹介いただく has just introduced him to an audience and he has now taken the turn to introduce himself.

---

[EDIT]

My explanation above was misleading. ご紹介いただく is also a humble expression for 紹介してもらう.

Comment: Thanks, it was difficult for me to understand this sentence because the subject is hidden. Things would be more clear when 私は is appended to the beginning...

Comment: @JimmyYang: 私は would be redundant and unnatural because everyone in the audience knows the speaker is the Tanaka who has been just introduced.

Comment: I understand the でございます part.  But, in reference to oneself, ご紹介いたただいた doesn't make much sense to me.  Isn't it saying, "I'm Tanaka who was just introduced"?  In which case, ご紹介いたただいた sounds a bit pompous, right?

Comment: ただいま～氏より丁寧な紹介をいただきました田中と申します。ただいまご紹介をいただきました田中でございます。ただいま紹介をいただきました田中です。ただいま紹介を受けました田中です。ただいま紹介の田中です。Arranged in the order of politeness.

Comment: @samhana So the honorific usage here is not toward Tanaka himself but toward the individual who introduced him.   I think that makes sense now.

Comment: @A.Ellett: edited

Comment: I'm confused again. So, the receiver of いただく actually is not Tanaka but the speaker who introduced him? What is going on there? Since いただく modifies 田中, it should be 田中? What should the full sentence look like?「[somebody]が田中が紹介していただきました」(Tanaka introduced himself [somebody humbly receive it]) can be reworded to「僕は[somebody]の紹介していただいた田中です」(I am Tanaka, who somebody is humbly receiving (Tanaka's) introduction). Who is doing 紹介 now, I don't get it.

Comment: @JimmyYang: from 田中が（[somebody]に）紹介してもらいました to （[somebody]に）紹介してもらった田中 to ご紹介いただいた田中.

Comment: Thanks, it took me around ten minutes to wrap my head on who is doing what...

Comment: @JimmyYang: I understand. More formal ご紹介に預かりました might have given you a harder time still.